# Checking for uniqueness within a string

Tags: c++, strings, interview-questions

I saw this interview question in the book *Cracking the Coding Interview*:

> Implement an algorithm to determine if a string has all unique characters

The authors solution uses bit-shifting for a pretty efficient solution.

I wanted to give it a shot to discover some new things and practice some. I'd like for this to be a discussion of how I can improve my programming and also, what the correct answer may be. Did I leave out any edge-cases? Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

// Uses an iterator to display the map.
void displayMap(map<char, int> displayCharacters)
{
    for (map<char, int>::iterator itr = displayCharacters.begin(), end = displayCharacters.end(); itr != end; ++itr)
    {
        cout << itr->first << " --> " << itr->second << endl;
    }
}

// Checks for uniqueness for a given string and returns a boolean.
bool isUnique(int stringLength, string alphabet, map<char, int> uniqueCharacters)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < stringLength; i++)
    {
        if (uniqueCharacters[alphabet[i]] == 1)
        {
            return false;
        }

        uniqueCharacters[alphabet[i]]++;
    }

    return true;
}

// Maps individual characters found in stringRead and sets a value to them.
// Returns the mapped map.
map<char, int> readString(string stringRead, map<char, int> uniqueCharacters)
{
    for (int i = 0, strLen = stringRead.length(); i < strLen; i++)
    {
        uniqueCharacters[stringRead[i]] = 0;
    }

    return uniqueCharacters;
}

int main()
{
    // Create a map to store a key character and value int. 
    // Create a string to hold a variable string to test.
    map<char, int> uniqueCharacters;
    string testString = "aaabbbccc";
    int stringLength = testString.length();

    // uniqueCharacters is mapped to the above string and the displayed using displayMap.
    uniqueCharacters = readString(testString, uniqueCharacters);
    displayMap(uniqueCharacters);

    if (isUnique(stringLength, testString, uniqueCharacters))
    {
        cout << "Unique string!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Not unique!\n";
    }

    cin.ignore();
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: @rafa you can use a bool array of uniqueCharacters instead of integer since you are not keeping any record of frequency of letters.

Comment: @aa1992 I was thinking of doing that as well. In any case, in an interview setting, if asked, 'how would you improve this?', that would be a good answer :)

Comment: Knowing whether the requirements need to handle otherwise-trivial character sets makes a big difference. For a simple ascii string, [a lookup table like this](http://pastebin.com/wgm22LLi) would probably be sufficient and near-optimal.

Answer (score 3):

This solution is inefficient:

1. There is no point counting the characters in the entire string: once you found a duplicate, you can stop counting, because you know the result is false

   - This also implies that the map of counts is wasted space
2. Iterating over the alphabet to check character counts is inefficient: it would be better to iterate over the map values

Instead of a `map`, it would be more efficient to use a `set`.

Instead of a `set`, you could also consider a boolean array of the size of the alphabet, values initialized to `false`,
and use that to track characters seen so far.
The disadvantage of this approach over a `set` is that it might use more space.

You are also violating some good practices:

- `using namespace std` is considered bad practice
- `readString` is poorly named: it doesn't "read a string", it initializes a map of character counts to all zero values
- No need to pass `stringLength` together with `testString`. You can derive that value from `testString`